# How do I improve Mediapipe Pose Estimation landmark consistency across devices

Tags: google-mlkit, mediapipe

I am currently working on a Mediapipe Pose Estimation for a fitness project to use across different mobile devices. We had been using the Mediapipe AAR full version. What I had found for example, is that on a Samsung S21, the elbow point will be estimated to the back of the elbow whereas on the iPhone, it would be estimated more towards the middle of the elbow. This would have a significant impact on our ability to give angle feedback to users and make it difficult to reference.

Is there any step or setting that I should do so that I can get more consistent results across different devices? Would it be better to use MLKit Mediapipe version? Or would the only way be to use an external camera to standardize the results.

Thank you.

Comment: The ML Kit Pose Detection is built on top of the MediaPipe pipeline with some tweaks. The version of the models could be different from the latest MediaPipe one. You could give it a try. However, I won't expect there will be too big an improvement.

Comment: If you are talking about the Z value for each landmark. In the ML Kit documentation, it is marked as experimental https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/pose-detection#z_coordinate which has lower accuracy compared with X, Y values.   So I would suggest to rely on it a bit less than relying on X,Y.

Comment: Hi Steven, Thanks for your response. So far we didn't really intend to use the Z value as I think it is still listed as experimental and some of the values don't always seem to be accurate. What my question is really about is that if I were to use a Xiaomi phone and compare it to an iPhone for example, how do I get more consistent data for the X and Y coordinates when using different devices and cameras. Thank you.

Comment: Oh now I see what you mean.  Is it possible to provide some specific example images that you can observe the issue with?  If you have concerns sharing your own images, feel free to use some from https://www.pexels.com/

Comment: Actually do you see the issue only in streaming mode or with single image as well?  For streaming mode with camera input, the image frames taken by different camera hardwares could be slightly different, which could result in different detection results.